# Spring MVC with Servlet 3.0 Web.xml giving broken link for <error-page> tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

location tag is giving a broken link in IBM RAD 8.0 IDE. And when 404 happens, system is not navigating to the controller with RequestMapping error1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Dashboard</display-name>
<error-page>
<location>/errors1</location>
</error-page>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DashBoard</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DashBoard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

1. Spring Jars version: 4.0.0
2. Servlet Jar version: 3.0.1
3. IDE IBM Rational Software Architect version: 8
4. IBM Websphere Application Server version: 8.5